# How to access JioFiber's admin panel remotely?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, nat

I want to access my jiofiber router's admin panel from the internet. Can't simply forward the port because the ISP's using Carrier Grade Network Address Translation (CGNAT). I don't have access to the intermediate routers between my LAN and Internet gateway as they're on the ISP's infrastructure.

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: I'd check the manual/manufacturer/ISP to see if it's even theoretically possible. It's a basic set of security switches, 'allow admin access over a)LAN b)WAN c)WiFi?' which may not even be switched on.

Comment: I don't have root access of the router. Hence, can't configure it for VPN